# Passing PHP headers to NGinx Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, proxy, php-fpm

I have nginx setup as a proxy in front of APACHE, which in turn talks to PHP-FPM.

It turns out, nginx is cutting out (or better to say not passing through) headers that are set directly in PHP via the header('foo: bar') command.

Namely I see the following picture:

PHP I set the following headers:
- cache-control
- pragma
- expires

And I see these if I open the page not through the nginx proxy, but directly through apache.

Now, when I open the page through nginx > all of the above are missing, and cache-control is totally replaced :/

I have the following extra directives in the nginx config, aiming to cache all images and static files for at least 30 days:

```
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
access_log off;
expires       30d;
keepalive_timeout 30;
keepalive_requests 1000;
reset_timedout_connection on;
client_body_timeout 10;
send_timeout 2;
```

whatever I try does not work > seems like nginx is generally ignoring all headers coming its way from apache. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why are you using Apache at all in this scenario? It is redundant.

Comment: the application uses mod_rewrite heavily and we do not have the resources to port it yet

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having this exact "issue" at the moment